# Disabling user interaction of all views besides one

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

I'm trying to simulate a UIAlertView behavior. Basically I want to present a view and disable the user interaction of all other views on screen (besides the presented view). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: did u try  self.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pretend alert view should consist of two views. The first one is the size of the screen and has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`. This prevents any touches going through to the views underneath. You then add, as a subview of this view, your actual alert window, with whatever buttons etc. you like.

You can contain both of these in a new `UIWindow` which you can set the `windowLevel` on to ensure they are on top of anything else in the screen.

You can also add a very slight `backgroundColor` to the screen-sized view which will dim everything behind it, if that is appropriate for your interface.

Comment: perfect and easy solution. It even works on "disabling" the tab and navigation bars :) thks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a view (with user interaction disabled) with black background with an alpha of 0.3 to the applications' main window whenever you show your custom alert. This, in addition to preventing user interaction, also adds that subtle darkening effect to the UI behind your custom alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Call `[view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` on all the views you want user interaction to be disabled. Don't forget to call `[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` on them again before you dismiss your custom alert view.